# Remove two LinearLayout's inside a inflater layout

Tags: android, parent, android-linearlayout, removechild, layout-inflater

I have a xml file named socio_form_organization.xml that have two layout's. This xml file is inflated in a layout named content how we can see by the code below

**socio_form_organization.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sfo_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/sfo_layout2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="51dp"
      android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
      android:baselineAligned="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/sfo_btOrganization"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:hint="@string/sfo_btOrganization" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/sfo_etEmpresa"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.14"
          android:hint="@string/sfo_etEmpresa"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:scrollHorizontally="false" />


      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/sfo_ivRemove"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_height="60dp"
          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:src="@drawable/tb_no_delete" />

  </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sfo_etTitulo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:hint="@string/sfo_etTitulo"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout where is inflated the **socio_form_organization.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/se_contentOrganization"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            layout="@layout/socio_form_organization" />
```

In my class i do the inflation

```
    LayoutInflater inflaterOrganization=
    (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout organization =    
    (LinearLayout)inflaterOrganization.inflate(R.layout.socio_form_organization, null);
    LinearLayout lLayoutOrganization;
    lLayoutOrganization = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.se_contentOrganization);
    lLayoutOrganization.addView(organization);
```

But now á need to remove the two layout inside the content when i click in ImageButton but i can't.

I try with

```
    View toRemove = (View) view.getParent();
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.se_content);
    vg.removeView(toRemove);
```

But only works when I have one layout. In this case I have two layout and don't work.

I do not know if I could make you understand. Anyone can help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error? If so, please post the logcats.

Comment: Hy Sam.I don't have errors. Simply when i click in the imagebutton to remove the content inflated nothing happens and the content is not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing two ids that do not exist in the layouts you provided:

```
lLayoutOrganization = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.se_contentOrganization);
```

Where is `se_contentOrganization`? Did you mean `se_contentEmail`?

And when you try to remove the views:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.se_content);
```

Where is `se_content`? Or did you mean `se_contentEmail`? Or `sfo_layout`?

**Addition**

Try this:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.se_contentOrganization);
LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sfo_layout);
parent.removeView(child);
```

If you are using socio_form_organization.xml multiple times then try:

```
LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent(); 
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) child.getParent(); 
parent.removeView(child);
```

Comment: Sorry the mistakes sam. Already upgraded. Is not se_contentEmail but yes se_contentOrganization.

Comment: Ok, which LinearLayout are you trying to remove? `se_contentOranization`?

Comment: I need to remove thw two linearLayouts. android:id="@+id/sfo_layout2" and android:id="@+id/sfo_layout2" .  When i try  when click in the image button                                                           View toRemove = (View) view.getParent();
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.se_contentOrganization);
    vg.removeView(toRemove);   don't work

Comment: (Hehe, I assume you meant `sfo_layout` and `sfo_layout2`.) My latest answer should do that, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sam if you can see my answer below I apreciate :) :)

Comment: Sam I'm succeed.  I have to remove the two layout's separate and not simultaneously.                                                                                                                                                                     View toRemoveOrganization = (View) view.getParent();
   View toRemoveOrganization2 = (View) toRemoveOrganization.getParent();
   ViewGroup teste = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.se_contentOrganization);
   teste.removeView(toRemoveOrganization);
   teste.removeView(toRemoveOrganization2);